# Is it wiser to go for opencart over prestashop

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, prestashop

I have recently been using prestashop and found out there are lot of plugins and modules that need to purchased which turns out quite expensive for me,i'm planing for a new online shop with more than 1000 products.So i'm thinking to go with opencart. Is it a wise decision?

Comment: You should read to make up your mind: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/250qjd/why_you_should_never_use_opencart_personal/

Comment: A really good thing to read is this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both frameworks installed and in my opinion they are both about the same in terms of performance, code quality and features.

You will probably still need to purchase some modules for Opencart but they are generally much cheaper than Prestashop modules.

So if budget is the main concern go with Opencart.

It's not difficult to learn how to make your own Opencart modules, I haven't tried making any Prestashop modules so I can't comment on that.